# Write SQL Code to automate the changing of the parameter year and period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If the day of the current date = 14 then the values of the parameter need to change.
The month and possibly year will need to advance by 1
    - May need to consider that on the 14th day of the month there may be a technical problem that prevents this process from running.
Example Friday is the 14th when the sql script is run on the sql server and sees that its the 14th then the field prmstring needs to be updated from 201305 to 201306.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what worked

```
  DECLARE @curentday VARCHAR(2)
  select @curentday =datepart(day,getdate())  

  declare @yearmonth varchar (6)
  select  @yearmonth =convert(varchar,getdate(),112)

  If  @curentday in (14,15,16) 
  begin 
  if (select prmString11 from FC_App where prmName1='prmCurFCPrd')  <> @yearmonth
  begin
  update FC_App 
  set prmString11 = @yearmonth 
  where prmName1='prmCurFCPrd'
  update FC_App 
  set prmString11 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATEADD(dd,1-day((DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,-      1,GETDATE())),112)
  where prmName1='prmcurWIPPrd'
  End
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @start = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()-13), 0)
SET @stop  = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start)
```

The `-13` moves everything back 13 days.
- The 1st to 13th of each month, are moved to a date in the previous month
- The 14th onwards of each month, stay in the same month

The `DATEADD(DATEDIFF())` rounds the date down to the beginning of the month.

In this way the 1st to 13th of every month are rounded down to the 1st of the previous month.  And the 14th onwards are rounded down to the 1st of the current month.

The end date is then simply the value calculated above, plus 1 month.

Comment: I not sure if I explained it right. This will be added to a script that is run everyday. on the 14th the field prmstring needs to be updated, the field is made up of year and period. 201305 so on the 14th it needs to be updated to the next period.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select  
    substring(
        convert(
            varchar(10),
            dateadd(mm, 1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, dateadd(d,-13,getdate())), 0))
            ,112)
    ,1,6) as newDate
```